# Is $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with discrete metric homeomorphic to $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with usual metric?

Tags: general-topology

$d_0$ is the discrete metric on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $d_1$ is the metric on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ induced by the usual metric on $\mathbb R$.

Are $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with topology of $d_0$ and $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with topology of $d_1$ homeomorphic?

I don't know. the two are compact and disconnected. what more questions I can ask about the two? If they are homeomorphic how to prove that?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show that the identity mapping is continuous in both directions? Then you have exhibited a homeomorphism. This feels easier than verifying a bunch of topological properties (that won't guarantee homeomorphism anyway). Easier still: Can you show that either metric induces the discrete topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only homeomorphic, they are equal topologies.*

You can see this by noticing that all points are open in both topologies (the only topology that allows this is the discrete). Checking this for one is trivial (since it follows almost directly from the definition of discrete metric. You just need to consider the ball of radius $1/2$ around the points.). For the other, just take the intersection of an open ball of radius $1/2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with the set to see that the point is open in the induced topology.

---

*Just as a sidenote to justify my comment.

You can have homeomorphic topologies which are not equal. For instance, given $D=\{0,1\}$,

$$\tau_1=\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\emptyset\}, \quad \tau_2=\{\{1\},\{0,1\},\emptyset\}. $$

Those are obviously distinct topologies, but the "interchange" map is a homeomorphism.